# remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed while pushing from local to remote

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repo (via HTTPS) from git on mac and I have my Personal Access Token (PAT) activated. I was able to push and pull my code from local to remote successfully. Recently, I had to change my PAT, and after changing that, whenever I try to do `git push origin <my-branch-name>` or `git pull origin master` I get an error saying that 'Invalid username or Password and Authentication failed. I tried `$ git config -l` and did
`$ git config --global --unset credential.helper $ git config --system --unset credential.helper`
but it still throws me the same error.
I have been doing `git push https://<username>:<auth-token>@github.com/<repo-name>.git`, but I don't want to keep doing that for every command. Is there any way that I can update my PAT locally to push my changes to remote?

Comment: You mention mac (macOS, presumably), so look at your macOS keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Check within your Git repository what `git config --show-origin --show-scope -l` if you have anything else referencing a credential helper (like "manager") or the PAT (old one) itself.

Check if you have a resource file (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.curlrc`, `~/.git-credentials`) which could reference the old PAT.